# OpenLayers Multi-line drawing lines disappear

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

Normally the code draws by calculating the linestring that will occur in every map movement. But the lines drawn in a certain convergence disappear. In the sample code, the green line is the main line and it does not disappear, but the lines outside it disappear when you zoom in. You can try to get closer to the lines on the code.

The code example is as follows:[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OnurEk/ngv76ouL)

```
       var lineString = new ol.style.LineStrings({
            valLine:7,
            valDistance:150, 
            color: 'green',
            width: 4,
            widthLines:4,
            colorArray: ['blue', 'red', 'white', 'black', 'orange', 'blue', 'red', 'white', 'black', 'orange'],
            }
```

What can be the reason for this and how can it be solved?

Comment: I don't see the lines disappear as I zoom in on your fiddle (I only see a mainly green line to start, then as I zoom in I see additional different colored lines)

Comment: If you get close to one unit next to the red line, you will see the red line disappear, but you can get as close as you want to the main line (green line), not disappear. For the new fiddle you can try the convergence rate set on two lines.

http://jsfiddle.net/ngv76ouL/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are styling the central line (the real feature) as seven lines (not real features, just geometry used for styling).  If the real feature isn't in the area covered by the map's viewport plus the layer's renderBuffer it won't be styled (although it may remain visible when panned because the style function isn't rerun unless the resolution changes).  To avoid the outlying style lines disappearing a high zoom levels you need to set `renderBuffer` on the layer to a very large number, for example

```
            var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
                source: vectorSource,
                renderBuffer: 1e10,
                style:lineString
            });
```